# iOS frosted glass effect using CSS for on page content

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I want to achieve frosted glass effect on my site nav area for all browsers (cross browser)

The requirement is to make anything behind the header layer as iOS blue same as http://goo.gl/X5FEiH

Any content on page including images, text should also get blur as scrolled down behind this header. I Googled it and found many results, the common way of doing is loading two images, one orignal and 2nd blur filter but it doesn't work for on page text.

Here is what I have done till now http://goo.gl/m2s1dA

Need help, pls help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is currently only possible in WebKit nightlies and Safari 9, which is in beta.

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
```

See the [introductory blog post on webkit.org](https://www.webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/) for a discussion. From the post:

> #### Standardization
>
> WebKit proposed this feature to the CSS Working Group last year, and it is currently in the Editor’s Draft of the CSS Filters Level 2 specification.

You might be able to achieve the same effect using `background-attachment: fixed`:

```
body {
    background-image: url(image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
    background-image: url(image-blurred.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The way `background-attachment: fixed` works is that the background image is kind of applied to the entire view port while the element acts like a mask, only revealing the portion of the background image behind the elements content box.